# How to create a diagonal "gradient" background with CSS

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

does anyone here know how to create a style blue gradient that looks like this? (image below)
[image: Image reference]

I only manage to make a solid color, but gradients seem to not know how
(This is my code)

```html
<div style="background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-100deg, #fff 50%, #063852 0%); height:300px">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated: Manage to solve it. Just by adding extra color code to it.

```html
<div style="background: -webkit-linear-gradient(256deg, #fff 53%, #6d87bf 20%, #011520 100%); height:300px">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead using `background : -webkit-linear-gradient`. Please use `background-color: linear-gradient`. I made few changes to your code and got the output that you required. If you want to increase the gradient change the **%** value which next to the color.

```html
<div style="background-image: linear-gradient(-170deg, #fff 50%, #063852 110% );
  height:300px"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm looking for a gradient to apply inside the bottom diagonal box just like the image above

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-170deg, #fff 50%, #063852 110% );height:300px"></div>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.